# MsBuild conditional ProjectReferences doesn't affect transitive references?

Tags: msbuild

I have an (new sdk-style) msbuild project where i'm using conditional project references depending on some command line parameter for msbuild.

For example:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="Some\Project.csproj" Condition="'$(Customer)'='BigOne'"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Apparently, this does only half of it's work. It does NOT build the conditionally included project if the condition evaluates to false. So far so good.

But what completely irritates me is that is *does* build the transitive (2nd and further levels) project references of that project.

Is that to be expected? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To yet again answer my own question: It seems that msbuild builds all projects it finds in project.assets.json, which initially contains all transitive project references (as it is not aware of my conditions).
It works fine when starting msbuild with /restore...